# Windows Media Player 12 doesn't recognize RTSP protocol

Tags: windows-7, streaming, windows-media-player, mpeg

I am trying to stream a live feed through RTSP to Windows Media Player 12 and get the error:

> "Windows Media Player cannot play the file because the specified
>   protocol is not supported. If you typed a URL in the Open URL dialog
>   box, try using a different transport protocol (for example, "http:" or
>   "rtsp:")."

- I have tried the feed with both MPEG4 and MJPEG, but WMP doesn't work with either one of them, but I can get the feed with VLC just fine.
- I have read [this Knowledge Base document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940029/en-us) and tried the resolutions suggested and they have not worked.
- I have removed WMP through `Turn Windows Features On and Off` and then manually deleted WMP from Program Files and also the files in the User directory. Yes, I reboot after turning off WMP.
- I have turned off the Firewall in an attempt to verify that it is not blocking ports (you would think it would not be blocking ports since I can get the feed through VLC, but I tried it just in case).
- I have also reduced my IE security settings to the lowest settings to see if it was a settings issue. Still got the error.
- I do not have McAffee (others have suggested that this might cause some issues with streaming).
- I am running Windows 7 x64 Professional. Other computers using Windows 7 x64 Pro can get the RTSP stream from Windows Media Player 12 (I have verified that they have the same build of WMP that I do).
- I have compared registry settings between those computers that work and mine for Windows Media Player with no success.
- I have tried to connect to different RTSP feeds from different encoder/decoders that I have and I get the same error as stated above, but again I can get the feeds with VLC.

(Yes, I know, why try to use Windows Media Player if VLC works? The answer is VLC doesn't work consistently, (drops ack signals and feed is lost), and I was trying to use a standard media player as a replacement.)

So the questions are: Why does my Windows Media Player 12 not recognize the RTSP protocol? And, how can I fix it so that it does?

Comment: Is it possible that the working Windows 7 systems have codecs installed that aren't present on your system, or vice versa? Most installed codecs should be listed in Control Panel - Programs.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but forgot to mention that I have also installed K-Lite mega pack for both 32-bit and 64-bit and still got the same error. (Someone had suggested to do both depending on the bit of the player.)

Comment: Installing the K-Lite codec pack definitely isn't recommended - you're likely just making the problem worse. Also, did you check for other codec differences between the systems?

Comment: I haven't checked for exact codec differences, but I have checked for codec packages that have been installed. I can look into the exact codec differences. Why would K-Lite make things worse?

Comment: Please do check for exact codec differences as well. As for K-Lite, see http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Why_Codec_Packs_Are_Bad

Comment: So I checked the video codecs in System Information-Components and the codecs installed are identical for those computers that have WMP 12 that can stream RTSP and mine which cannot. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp` registry key exist on the working systems and/or non-working system? If so, what are the contents?
Same question for the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Media Foundation\SchemeHandlers\rtsp:` key.

Comment: Both machines have HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp has
Source Filter of type REG_SZ with Data = {5DA153D0-6F75-409e-9FAB-EB62F843CF7C} 
and 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Media Foundation\SchemeHandlers\rtsp has
{E9F4EBAB-D97B-463e-A2B1-C54EE3F9414D} of type REG_SZ with Data = Net Scheme Handler

Comment: Are you sure that `{5DA153D0-6F75-409e-9FAB-EB62F843CF7C}` is correct? It doesn't give any results on Google.

Comment: Yep, that is copied and pasted from my registry.

Comment: I suggest that you try renaming the `rtsp` key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. It certainly isn't part of a default Windows 7 install and the fact that there aren't any references on the entire web is suspicious.

Comment: Well I've given up at this point, I will have to look for hack of sorts to solve my problem. Thanks Tim for all your help with this.